# Solid rocket boosters and 3d printing

Tags: rockets, booster

My question is similar to one concerning 3d printing for enhnaced performance with hybrid rockets, but concerns using it to improve performance of solid chemical rockets by 3d Printing the solid rocket fuel 
into more efficient geometry,to maximize burn surface and thus allow for more precise and greater thrust control. I am wondering if any material on the subject exist and maybe were to find it?

Comment: Yes, people are looking into this. What precisely is your question?

Comment: Is 3D printing of fuels the new term for fuel injection, irrespective of whether the fuel is solid or liquid?

Comment: @Fred "3D printing" is the new term for "how can we do this cool thing that I just thought of?".